# How to commit the files to a branch with Source Tree?

Tags: tortoisehg, atlassian-sourcetree

I have two branches X and Y . I committed some files to X branch and some to Y branch. And both the commits are pushed to the central repository. Now when I am downloaded the code at branch Y , it has the files from X branch and vice versa. How can I restrict that the downloaded code should contain only one branch which I used with hg clone ? ( hg clone - rev branch X ---- This has to contain only X branch code)

Answer (score 0):

Answer is mainly written for SourceTree:

Do you have the branches x and y on your remote repository?
It sounds like you pushed the local x to remote x and y and same with local y.

Because as far as I know files can only come into another branch from a push or a merge (on remote repository).

Be sure to push local x to remote x and local y to remote y.

If you pull a remote branch it goes to the current "selected" (change with checkout)